# Exporting Geotiff from GEE gives 'Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input':...Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to export a geotiff from GEE and it keeps on giving me this error message:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)
```

Here is my code:

```
var AOI = ee.FeatureCollection(AOI);

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var filtered = s2.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31') // << change date range here
              .filterBounds(AOI)
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .map(function(image){return image.clip(AOI)});
              
var addEVI = function(image) {
var EVI = image.expression(
      '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      // 'NIR' : image.select('B8').divide(10000),
      // 'RED' : image.select('B4').divide(10000),
      // 'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000)}).rename('EVI');
      'NIR' : image.select('B8'),
      'RED' : image.select('B4'),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2')})
      .rename('EVI');
      return image.addBands(EVI);
};

var with_evi = filtered.map(addEVI);
var greenest = with_evi.qualityMosaic('EVI');

Map.addLayer(with_evi, {min:0, max:0.5, bands:'EVI', palette: 'brown, lightgreen'}, 'EVI');

Export.image.toDrive({
image: with_evi.select('EVI'),
description: 'Chicago_2016EVI',
scale:10,
region: AOI
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to export an imageCollection. `Export.image.toDrive` requires an image as input data, not an imageCollection.

Also, you have an image in your code (`greenest`), so use:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
image: greenest,
description: 'Chicago_2016EVI',
scale:10,
region: AOI
});
```